# preg_replace replace colon and back slash

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
$subject = 'string://example.com/';

$search1 = ':';
$search2 = '/';
$replace = '_';
```

Desired output:

```
$string = string_example1.com_example.com_;
```

Is there any way of achieving this with preg_replace?

```
$string =  preg_replace(':', $replace, array($subject));
```

This is incorrect i know, but i need to remove slash and and colon and replace with underscore, and wherever they come together replace it with only only underscore

Thanks

Comment: preg_replace('/(:\/\/|\/)/','_',$subject);

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic, you're trying to replace forward slashes (or simply slashes), not backslashes, which lean back toward the start of the line. It's worth pointing this out as a lot of people get them mixed up and your post title is likely to make more people think "/" is a backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Use delimiters in your pattern:

```
preg_replace('/(:\/\/|/\{1})/', '_', $subject);
```

Comment: thanks this replaces but can i replace only one underscore where i have `: & /` both together

Comment: right now it returns the result as `string__example1.com_example.com_`

Comment: preg_replace('/(:\/\/|\/)/','_',$subject); Please update this

Comment: Do you want change only when `:/` or `://` together?

Comment: Try this: `preg_replace('/(:\/\/|/\{1})/', '_', $subject);` It change `://` and '/` if there are only 1 slash.

Comment: Thats what i commented above

Comment: Now I really do not know, what you want. Now do you have the solution?

Comment: Please edit your ans to `preg_replace('/(:\/\/|/\{1})/', '_', $subject);` this is the required solution....and then il accept it :)

Comment: I've did it. Thank you.

Comment: after the | sign the slash not escaped

Answer (score 1):

I think `str_replace` would be more convenient, if you're trying to replace a specific character, and `str_ireplace` for array of characters

EDIT

Example:

```
$subject= str_ireplace(array(':','/'),'_', $subject);
```

I think it would go like that.

Comment: this is a comment. or give an example.

Answer (score 1):

INPUT :

```
$subject = 'string://example.com/';

$string = str_replace('___', '_', preg_replace('/[:\/]/', '_', $subject));
```

OUTPUT :

```
string_example.com_
```

Hope This Helps

Answer (score 0):

That's what 'd do:

```
$subject = 'string://example.com/';
$string = preg_replace('~://|/~', '_', $subject);
echo $string,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
string_example.com_
```